Recover damaged & luks-encrypted BTRFS partition
Here's my problem:
I have a Virtual Machine that I had to reset because the UI became very buggy after I tried to mount a hot-pluggable virtual disk image to copy some files.
Well that was actually premature, should not have done that - but shit sometimes happens.
The Virtual Disk is encrypted with luks1 and the file system used is btrfs.
I also have backed up the virtual disk in working state.
I made some changes to the certain files [a password db and my firefox profile &
some other documents] that are not in my last backup.
Therefore I would like to restore my btrfs partition
When I enter the password the following error appears (when I start up the vm):

Enter passphrase for hd0,gpt2 (91188ec2-c31a-4812-a8c8-654cf5c793fb):
Attempting to decrypt master key...
Slot 0 opened
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
==========================================================================
I tried to restore the partition using a live-system
but the partition is not mountable
Since I backed up the corrupted virtual disk to a safe location.
I am capable to start over if something goes sideways.
Just need to copy the corrupted virtual disk from backup location to
working directory of the VM. So creating an image of my vm partition won't be necessary
GParted shows the follwing errors
when I open the information window for my btrfs partition.
So it does not recognize the filesystem.

Encryption: luks
Path: /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt
UUID: 91188ec2-c31a-4812-a8c8-654cf5c793fb
Status: Open
Partition
Path /dev/sda2
1st Sector: 618496
Last Sector: 188731619
Total Sectors: 188113124
Warning:
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:

The file system is damaged
The file system is unknown to GParted
There is no file system available [unformatted]
The device entry /dev/mapper/sda_crypt2 is missing

GParted vm disk image corrupted

I used btrfs-tools and testdisk:
Command: btrfs rescue super-recover /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt
Output: No valid btrfs found on /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt
==========================================================================
Additional Info's:
The ssd's of my host system and it's partitions are in healthy state - so no issues here!
The vm is an efi system & uses gpt as partition table!
The screenshots from GParted show the disk before the Data Corruption occurred:
GParted screenshot virtual disk info

dmesg shows an this error message when I attempt to mount the my btrfs partition
with this command: mount /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt or /dev/sda1
/dev/mapper/sda2_crypt: Can't open blockdev
/dev/sda1: Can't open blockdev

Command:dmesg | tail
Output: systemd-gpt-auto-generator[3165]: (the boot loader did not set EFI variable LoaderDevicePartUUID.)
systemd-gpt-auto-generator[4398]: EFI loader partition unknown, exiting.
This output shows a few time with diffrent numbers between the [].

Command: hexdump /dev/sda2 | grep LUKS
Output: 00000000 4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01 61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
So I guess the luks header is still there!

The testdisk results: see attached Code (testdisk log!)
I would like to restore the partition to working state.
Help would be appreciated
Attachments:
testdisk log:
https://pastebin.com/YcPNEcm9
=======================================================================
Additional Info's [26th May 2024]:
I recreated the problem on a copy of my working vm disk image.
As I stated above tried to mount a hot-pluggable virtual disk image for backing
up important files, while the vm was running.
The UI / Caja (the File Manager) became very buggy.
I decided to shut the vm down, which lead to the following errors.
See Screenshot below

The system tried to write changes to the system disk but the system disk was
somehow in a read-only state.
If my understanding of btrfs is correct. Then it is possible that entries were
written in the journal but the changes were not made to the data on the disk.
I backup the luks header as suggested and some files from the root filesystem
like the folder 'boot', 'etc' and the files cryptfile.bin, initrd.img, initrd.img.old, vmlinuz, vmlinuz.old

I noticed that my working VM Image shows the text 'Welcome to GRUB!' when I start the VM and asks me to enter my passphrase
The corrupt VM Image is not showing that welcome message above, which is kinda odd. I think there is also s.th. wrong with GRUB in addition to the filesystem corruption of the root partition
